# connecting to BSNL wireless broadband

Tags: broadband

I am unable to connect to my BSNL broadband (wireless) from ubuntu11.10 .It attempts to connect but then shows "wireless network disconnected" . Though it connects automatically when I plug in the jack in the wired mode. I can also connect to other wireless networks elsewhere...The wireless connection works fine when I use Windows 7. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since BSNL is the state owned telecom provider in India, it provides both landline and mobile services. Usually BSNL broadband is associated with fixed-line services.

Its limited but I have a tutorial [here](http://www.beubuntu.co.cc/2010/06/how-to-connect-bsnl-broadband-in-linux_27.html)

This may help for [wireless connections](http://www.crazyengineers.com/community/threads/how-to-setup-bsnl-3g-data-card-in-ubuntu-10-10-guide.37747/)

Comment: Bsnl provides wireless also

Answer (score 0):

There is another question where there are instruction on how to configure BSNL broadband wireless connection in Ubuntu 10.10; try to see if this solves your problem:

[Connecting with a BSNL Broadband Internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24285/connecting-with-a-bsnl-broadband-internet)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
sudo lshw -C network
iwconfig
lspci
```